# MySQLi is not working , no errors , no inserted info

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been doing all people told me to make it works , but there is no errors and no inserted rows:

Any idea?

```
private $db;

// Constructor - open DB connection
function __construct() 
{
    $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'sampleinyoudb');
    $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        sendResponse(500, "Could not connect to the database!");
        exit();
    }
}

// Destructor - close DB connection
function __destruct() 
{
    $this->db->close();
}
```

...

```
        if($stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Users (id,email) VALUES (?, ?)"))
        {
            $test1 = 1; //Empty
            $test2 = 'asdasd@gmail.com'; //Empty
            $stmt->bind_param("is", $test1, $test2);
            $stmt->execute();   
            if ( false===$stmt ) 
            {
              die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
            }               
            $stmt -> close();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $this->db->error);
        }
        echo 'Any Errors: '.$this->db->error.PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Since you have specified [`autocommit(FALSE)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php), where are you [manually committing](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php) your transaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have specified [`autocommit(FALSE)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php), but are not [manually committing](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php) your transaction.  At some point after `$stmt->execute()` you must put:

```
$this->db->commit();
```